# Symbolic equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, polynomials

I have the following symbolic equation e.g. `syms F1 F2 G` in Matlab :

```
eqn =
 
G*((1.1*(F1 - 1.0)*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (1.1*F1*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G))) - 1.0*(G*(((F1 - 1.0)*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (F1*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G))) - (0.526*F1^2*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + 0.55)^2 + 1.0*G^2*((1.0*F1*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25)^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G))^2 - (1.0*(F1 - 1.0)*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25)^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G))^2) - 2.1*G*(((F1 - 1.0)*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (F1*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)))*((0.5*F1^2*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) - (0.5*(F1 - 1.0)^2*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G))) + (0.277*(F1 - 1.0)^2*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25)^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G))^2 - (0.579*F1^2*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.277*F1^2*((0.132*F2^2)/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) - (0.25*G*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G) + 0.25)^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F2 - (1.0*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2)*(F2 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G)) + (0.526*F2^2*(G*(F1 - 1.0) - 0.526*F1^2))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + F1*G))^2 + (0.579*(F1 - 1.0)^2*((0.132*F1^2)/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) - (0.25*G*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G) + 0.25))/(0.526*(F1 - 1.0)^2 + G*(F1 - (1.0*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2)*(F1 - 1.0))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + (0.526*F1^2*(G*(F2 - 1.0) - 0.526*F2^2))/(0.526*(F2 - 1.0)^2 + F2*G)) + 0.302 == 0.08
```

It's a big one but all the values are in the range `[0.0,1.0]` and I want to isolate `G` in a polynomial form. So I call `eqn = isolate(eqn,G)` and the result I am getting is as follows:

```
eqn =
 
G == root(625000000040358827391239865006471429713989707011023710947483778000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2*z^4 + 312500000020179413695619932503235714856994853505511855473741889000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^2*z^4 + 1289062500020179413695619932503235714856994853505511855473741889000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*z^4 - 625000000040358827391239865006471429713989707011023710947483778000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2*z^4 - 1601562500040358827391239865006471429713989707011023710947483778000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*z^4 + 312500000020179413695619932503235714856994853505511855473741889000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*z^4 + 3000601753982512388900693004011126908350061726894072319683884222378588840916297186822703224606812000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2*z^3 + 2342935616106242608066626518506190225774889065624622776607849292670361310610864791215135483071208000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2^2*z^3 + 657666137873724706683875204682023422575020575631357439894628074130102530305432395607567741535604000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2*z^3 + 657666137873724706683875204682023422575020575631357439894628074130102530305432395607567741535604000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^3*z^3 - 3329434822916829668092439325529226336199919929071658936449791403855749481069013384626487095374614000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2*z^3 - 3329434822916829668092439325529225359637419929071658936449791403863561981069013384626487095374614000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^2*z^3 - 328833068936862353341937602341011711287510287815678719947314037067004390152716197803783870767802000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^3*z^3 + 1027603340363883342999258670787967947500152085638092103181406855589843750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*z^3 + 657666137872452169608779564270567280856194532812311388303924646337133780305432395607567741535604000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^2*z^3 - 2384039749664629039340454943916948582850314459091862926310127748238879390152716197803783870767802000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*z^3 + 2712872818602763929757488186669417412419150789726587697848145213091040030305432395607567741535604000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*z^3 - 328833068936862353341937602341011711287510287815678719947314037063098140152716197803783870767802000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2*z^3 - 1356436409303290770491387553951892918787814459091862926310127748234973140152716197803783870767802000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*z^3 + 1272537075095640411456141718826042819046051590703427792968750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*z^3 - 940741328805673681968816073414179915105671695276044851370511997499693202896854870689460386676852634989271776251529288970232300926000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2*z^2 + 1157003703195776300329994791982601389079448906421721089042991435235524505133356019623560595303813535220149078929008368277209228836000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*F2^2*z^2 + 692039598201819774843505038693588663631455071359435822333845332615249906853885982677692134354342859502798157858016736554418457672000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2^3*z^2 + 616347767133424723237486859228071452264769777634700998657651281065358489508356019623560595303813535220149078929008368277209228836000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2^4*z^2 - 3352066803694282262925247142005586287407750601824267411216086263368211950150693126158918443722848699538245394645041841386046144180000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2^2*z^2 - 2270754931569579108740231276496526413778392344250227230445405955038053870623583832309710982842569152663245394645041841386046144180000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2^3*z^2 + 3314220888158880008321904642394756673199831360125422410838645027221688329966808848125885460891008021771920855180537657247441529762000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2^2*z^2 - 540655936059673482553547185746505632731273773664074005789223078824864959087173943430570943746715789062500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^5*F2*z^2 + 194636136953407406053873172383662178947065348341866575992011690763656688133512364149710893886124183529850921070991631722790771164000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*F2*z^2 - 616347767133424723237486859228071452264769777634700998657651281067413696189078696161258730083743648501399078929008368277209228836000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^4*z^2 + 421711630190461058401162747624628826832105309084300599240293668352153860640845480695642088728104863409048157858016736554418457672000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2*z^2 + 1232695534265510399205493344952130495587001787373361742750396533199115340671744364037802932040845191534048157858016736554418457672000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^3*z^2 + 346019799081092815317840844038487915703562280615969952637926385701187098271772644661750117760191293032649078929008368277209228836000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2*z^2 - 600128089007000643689802953095560893031626438355537203267264682434404618735883065230582989076112781186100921070991631722790771164000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^2*z^2 + 540655936062351577092507932754529936814679128787020090385340154170166015625000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^6*z^2 + 86504949775562233672808223212701813639983871061223147566380919444064003061200343174739216215918440445662269732252092069302307209000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^4*z^2 - 1351639840157217990000750205390337507880070678925620617699463494169165516824647532700964802643284199218750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^5*z^2 - 2543487930722676537698134779930113281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^3*z^2 + 2384292678039351707515633527541383165028211114919253324011234875555439260342284559917522826459268706070662269732252092069302307209000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*z^2 - 432524748877744009129467634250538239540521223609050798685699942296619261238852805564680817159873647540811348661260460346511536045000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^2*z^2 - 2297787728265128521112305677832694787934105373092339280077149950103625852306774568489800003590062257812500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*z^2 + 783951107253576663849753490796889016390692600617225029172967079269235784555762402345602244050192430584188651338739539653488463955000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*z^2 + 519029698646812484158594435382087925437659746935595368197689769165110181981485296328213701922505978611473618393512552415813843254000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F2*z^2 + 113537746611697271357095956474481677117715602082229171285442081587961744481485296328213701922505978611473618393512552415813843254000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*z^2 - 173009899552396355380523338116445721364777558990556035085158195433058310873110157400573966198620658235074539464504184138604614418000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*z^2 - 270327968029836741276773592873250139940222456756594208329185538768963602938517176710320200072601437500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^6*F2*z + 284456881091126574059638426752737093756065387090894145929258444266088878552121728692090293834733079196997795485168936124864558223632812500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^5*F2*z - 347037394907268141979696523915493409032541052308550679913577386083350775346436091731736044087207498310670599231931499730025442374257791174072931394967156393249752000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*F2*z + 364104807820548293169399542966348108881766277270525600134243908864226726199000340248770069775486206175027237738638729468048787851496115075927068605032843606750248000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^4*z - 563224624648892870067771891999726746254048174268070331563272614226759792438319311027523807006210021885635507788900453335680026244640699640744740117614952623625868000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2*z - 1416595267912692033998748055259237180046025149393173639974195997713335248265413026959716474041847267049100703761108219652976799439906324640744740117614952623625868000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^3*z + 1120760111612616082690414313726248394654858410856316279571811126891045000776237695765253521762888626281345038129052657454345526804007903135190041571389585328688554000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2*z + 1689673873780498393437782491733672932920468592602830216594921103140555557138939457650131041621173476156832831307616057885703403900168059385190041571389585328688554000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2^2*z - 585981175105113857556918989555026761229926846108241913804229848598012274277641195416192940218749975866472502286462374684671560886601605151854137210065687213500496000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*F2*z - 270327968029836741276773592873250139940222456756594208329185538768963602938517176710320200072601437500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^5*F2^2*z + 270327968029836741276773592873250139940222456756594208329185538768963602938517176710320200072601437500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*F2^3*z - 1339047269480373504015085367952197971483049130332029580157490811482823289679799927398562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2^4*z - 364104807820548293169399542966347838553798248772831592841024539627833941221526517416213588208976693386170342808049537495945352305335958825927068605032843606750248000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*F2^2*z - 1012666496732223160398437512685432770863661881958462792650560515491586025090778820558419209588627307607481858135621431757155408037179730151854137210065687213500496000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2^3*z - 364104807820548293169399542966348108881766276601001965394057156855345829515686316785848221896471093334240189100991313296445533808929708825927068605032843606750248000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2^4*z + 2247209360739431326936455354960844698239105309447810075565250301958653701094590334727336682884339175331006914079764010809007328649296981629635343025164218033751240000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2^2*z + 2247209360739431326936455354960844968567073330179857404270155899004325494868363998801342472107418006747785612699060516776220635225312606629635343025164218033751240000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2^3*z - 3299699820841155626013742984252432454255839113492813673416683809739568324217650196754387848874091361168555705618005031143257983648121253694453014537746327050626860000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*F2^2*z + 270327968031175788546253966377265225308174654728077257459517568349121093750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^7*z - 810983904094196889273502085883803218608500063169973296943718719838174448530741411644839899963699281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^6*z - 91026201955137073292349885741587027220441569317631400033560977216391234726553844492541838122121632295302376408718625199938019548695317831481767151258210901687562000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^4*z - 142228440545563287029819213376367060074208526630957042602157785279215742954231481624024954977971232753416178483996112902332242811097656250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^5*z + 273078605863016080315064877975086410448205972696131823580640757861759610535291372215055482162401323620806255632153513644978480428914078494445301453774632705062686000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^3*z + 193430679131199221643318982511799102141578175201094906915219274217349109479057142966792118891996598934158129284211125209865071766855463418518232848741789098312438000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*z - 273078605863016080315064877975086410448205972696131823580640757860421397828076334493658199449401000614623987735917742313275190085628922244445301453774632705062686000000000000000000000000000000000*F2^2*z - 11378275213739656372664873279601574717274894486169339276277056975889619637636624159946091681030832449866424545004706615501967476222640255554698546225367294937314000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*z + 11378275213739656372664873279601845045242918565834841682116414055260195170260103777382858595182644997684723182652122787105221518789046505554698546225367294937314000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^2*z + 91026201957532212854334664991261698433560304574393776553603151001128902956493930312317304900084559548038714210249444491367017079296880331481767151258210901687562000000000000000000000000000000000*F2*z - 51202238583240795051514989885757100526282874371940262950739165693434760794885575522991697136062439416286862998684193016103831425156244668518232848741789098312438000000000000000000000000000000000*F1*z - 2395139561984779249674671213118735256762376520042173786075880937155123541172749490963250258918605697766590623132287873886718750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*z + 1263148349339290402242467782430012693895576216102482452117041254558159831050134628581834294173174733350960510666950880321330403695703783133372576897247179781879260535002446077668402518723311800386*F1^2*F2^2 + 341229648873486446833555427640005567152168231314121990121850811106154851010558271891793406352943964205631495400508305125479129885568744539184156606353181308462248206765281430039624122052543953032*F1^3*F2^3 - 703411995485294519643774341068005429136390661574185178985864225605355658182947739534558266084210014761649024535240586487611308254183004059847387741939065662389530391913203575099060305131359882580*F1^3*F2^2 - 568913762182253148119276853505466932922352992566557250975250527946126619809310686784217391010973159238192075335849295925072510726750000000000000000000000000000000*F1^5*F2 + 532797171048551296226996627248002645560306536336565935985821821350777069217924940100195881510978327987768181490329826033567248797978250886292977363410437544413769663530562860079248244105087906064*F1*F2 - 135163984015587894273126983188632355753252237029471416462911292910644531250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^6*F2^2 + 67581992007793947136563491594316177876626118514735708231455646455322265625000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*F2^4 - 874026819922037743060552054888007928255593681314392990438804379074216040781858760457596640937038171465622319907823042996003120453677566781420632082791675048492972807795844290118872366157631859096*F1^2*F2 + 532797171048551296226996627248002361103425454790550124286512067318811771501172320310036075282474059595523372179643041816176237824819012694217641514114512471903042913530562860079248244105087906064*F1^3*F2 - 778243058834505318363831455084009389051524524012891893537260374601154349948303594609162562659641137239021429190583978596306813740762623155885055666587028198644893766913203575099060305131359882580*F1^2*F2^3 + 142228440545563287029819213376367003558556279317427858997779009251243161456801730638887273575329111098610518833962323981268127681687500000000000000000000000000000*F1^5*F2^2 - 142228440545563287029819213376366733230588248141639312743812631986531654952327671696054347752743289809548018833962323981268127681687500000000000000000000000000000*F1^4*F2^3 - 142228440545563287029819213376366733230588248141639312743812631986531654952327671696054347752743289809548018833962323981268127681687500000000000000000000000000000*F1^3*F2^4 - 799195756572826944340494940872003968340459804504848903978732732026165603826887410150293822266467491981652272235494739050350873196967376329439466045115656316620654495295844290118872366157631859096*F1*F2^2 - 133199292762137824056749156812000661390076634084141483996455455337694267304481235025048970377744581996942045372582456508391812199494562721573244340852609386103442415882640715019812061026271976516*F1*F2^4 + 133199292762137824056749156812000803618517182042568075800448081379735206765655557177671923969529129706128896536418304535565688571139467495582661322014600020167283259632640715019812061026271976516*F1^2*F2^4 - 95783761087532424696720599803997970290306975048352977624690499006128768480562599291183103026869088099981081406552280182305295739755705433460240566908721777337352290882640715019812061026271976516*F1^4*F2 + 142228440545563287029819213376366733230588248141639312743812631986531654952327671696054347752743289809548018833962323981268127681687500000000000000000000000000000*F1^6*F2 + 95783761087532424696720599803998539204069157301501096901544004472926526849539577954160951294208401870847638480209592983233395420004299094285576416204646849848079040882640715019812061026271976516*F1^4*F2^2 + 532797171048551296226996627248002645560306536336565935985821821350777069217924940100195881510978327987768181490329826033567248797978250886292977363410437544413769663530562860079248244105087906064*F1*F2^3 - 95783761087532424696720599803998681432509698074509002751198881489044339691931475743513981391649168422723295372582456508391812199494562721573244340852609386103442415882640715019812061026271976516*F2 - 133199292762137824056749156812000661390076634084141483996455455337694267304481235025048970377744581996942045372582456508391812199494562721573244340852609386103442415882640715019812061026271976516*F1 + 143675641631298637045080899705998022148764547111763504126798322233566509537897213615270972087473752634084943058873684762587718299241844082359866511278914079155163623823961072529718091539407964774*F2^2 + 112246595023816198080085671024006082101141348801905349585424598561797267712013882668751037246235840187740900181284449275769682900758330033537667924647962536255363375000000000000000000000000000000*F1^5 - 20952697738321625976663485787994579288935285282236134411030856775761835608455647285364100305206207078163390717239064399696306712914943625535576416204646849848079040882640715019812061026271976516*F1^3 - 37415531674605399360028557008001979957566933614492919260477324172936726787576815085405398257376955329427094452747433777785142492912971180259416981161990634063840843750000000000000000000000000000*F1^6 + 181091173305904036405109456714000002106331485516535547356834145757591728015382888768922381422759092376069966895037836735413841927596939308350449530116923445091322780073961072529718091539407964774*F1^2 - 125716186426538491265934078081008533929021405856197609962094828405054504973842561136323754601796531731329282021354738327713849533540465698038190801758791457857184458529339821245046984743432005871*F1^4 + 23945940271883106174180149950999670358127424518627250687799720372261084922982868935878495347912292105680823843145614127097953049873640680393311085213152346525860603970660178754953015256567994129*F2^4 - 95783761087532424696720599803998681432509698074509002751198881489044339691931475743513981391649168422723295372582456508391812199494562721573244340852609386103442415882640715019812061026271976516*F2^3 + 67581992007793947136563491594316177876626118514735708231455646455322265625000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^8 - 270327968031175788546253966377264711506504474058942832925822585821289062500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*F1^7 + 23945940271883106174180149950999670358127424518627250687799720372261084922982868935878495347912292105680823843145614127097953049873640680393311085213152346525860603970660178754953015256567994129, z, 1)
```

Which seems very weird to me. How do these huge numbers appear ? Is this the wrong way to do it ? Also , after that I want to exctract the coefficients from the polynomial. I already tried `c=coeffs(eqn,G)` but it doesn't seem to work. It returns the previous result.

**UPDATE**: By the advice in the comments and removing the magic numbers , I finally managed to get a neat form without the big numbers, but still the `coeffs` doesn't appear to work to extract the coefficients.I also tried `c=sym2poly(eqn)` but I am getting

```
Error using sym/sym2poly (line 30)
Not a polynomial.
```

Comment: It converts decimal values to fractions, like `5.2731+1/5.2731=2880558361/527310000`. That is where the big numbers come from. Try making an expression _with symbols only_ and no magic numbers except for `1.0` or `^2` and see what the results are.

Comment: Great, [edit] the question with the new information.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: My problem for which the `coeffs` doesn't work is the that the expression is inside `root`. Even if i use `rhs()` the `root(...)` doesn't get away

Comment: The expression is a quadratic divided by a quadratic in terms of `G`. So you should collect terms and extract poly coefficients separately for numerator and denominator.